# Python API and dict

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I am trying to only print say both "devices", I have tried multiple ways but without any luck, How would I do so? Also further more how would I do something to print say the "model" of a single device or even both. I have posted my code as well as the response below.

```
<class 'dict'>
{'data': {'devices': [{'device': ’00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00’, 'model': 'H6159', 'deviceName': 'Closet', 'controllable': True, 'retrievable': True, 'supportCmds': ['turn', 'brightness', 'color', 'colorTem']}, {'device': '00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00', 'model': 'H6003', 'deviceName': 'Living Room', 'controllable': True, 'retrievable': True, 'supportCmds': ['turn', 'brightness', 'color', 'colorTem']}]}, 'message': 'Success', 'code': 200}
```

Comment: if you want to access the dict use rs[key], for example rs['data']['devices'][0]['model'] to get the device model for the first one in list

Comment: Refer to
[this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [this](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are want to access the dict rs' value by key. So, you want to access the dict use rs[key], for example rs['data']['devices'][0]['model'] to get the device model for the first one in list.

```
rs['data'] -> get the data value of rs which is another dict.
rs['data']['devices'] -> get the devices in data which is a list. So you can access its element by index for example 0.
rs['data']['devices'][0] -> get the first device in the devices list
rs['data']['devices'][0]['model'] -> get the value of first device model.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if i didn't understand your question correctly.

```
response = {'data': {'devices': [{'device': '00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00', 'model': 'H6159', 'deviceName': 'Closet', 'controllable': True, 'retrievable': True, 'supportCmds': ['turn', 'brightness', 'color', 'colorTem']}, {'device': '00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00', 'model': 'H6003', 'deviceName': 'Living Room', 'controllable': True, 'retrievable': True, 'supportCmds': ['turn', 'brightness', 'color', 'colorTem']}]}, 'message': 'Success', 'code': 200}


for device in response["data"]["devices"] :
    #you loop through your devices this way.
    print (device)
    print (device['model'])
    print (device['device'])
    


#Alternatively, if you wish to access device by index :
device = response["data"]["devices"][0]
print (device)


#then you can access whichever item you want afterwords

print (device['device'])
print (device['model'])
```